# How to handle click in the child Views, and touch in the parent ViewGroups?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, viewgroup

In my layout I have a structure like that:

```
--RelativeLayout
  |
  --FrameLayout
    |
    --Button, EditText...
```

I want to handle touch events in the RelativeLayout and in the FrameLayout, so I set the onTouchListener in these two view groups. But only the touch in the RelativeLayout is captured.

To try solve this, I wrote my own CustomRelativeLayout, and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent`, now the click in the child ViewGroup (FrameLayout) is captured, but the click in the buttons and other views doesn't make any effect.

In my own custom layout, I have this:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()`  for each child, otherwise it will remain an `onTouchEvent` for the parent.

[Intercept Touch Events in a ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    /*
    * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
    * If we return true, onTouchEvent will be called and we do the actual
    * scrolling there.
    */
...
    // In general, we don't want to intercept touch events. They should be 
    // handled by the child view.
    return false;
}
```

You need to return false to have the child handle it, otherwise you are returning it to the parent.

Comment: Suppose I want to override the touch events only for handling some of the children, what can I do inside this function to have it working ? I mean, for some children it would work as usual, and for some, the parent-view will decide if they will get the touch events or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your  custom solution will capture touch events from anywhere in your relative layout since the overridden method is set to always throw true.

For your requirement I guess its better to use 
the onClick method rather than using onTouch.

OnTouch method invokes different threads on every TouchEvent and  I guess that is the cause of your problem

Rather than handling these events its better to  try onClick method.

Comment: Thank you, but even If I set onClick in the two view groups, only the click in the first (RelativeLayout) is handled.

Comment: Sharing the code will surely  make things more  clear .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem with the following code:

Step 1: declare the EditText above the onCreate () method

```
public EditText etMyEdit;
```

Step 2: in the onResume () method the configuration ends:

```
etMyEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText);

etMyEdit.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps someone!