# How to vary between child and parent view group touch events

Tags: android, parent-child, android-view, touch-event, interception

I decided to post this question and answer in response [to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179769/how-to-handle-click-in-the-child-views-and-touch-in-the-parent-viewgroups#comment49963437_28180281) to this question:
 [How to handle click in the child Views, and touch in the parent ViewGroups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179769/how-to-handle-click-in-the-child-views-and-touch-in-the-parent-viewgroups)

I will paste the comment here:

> Suppose I want to override the touch events only for handling some of
>   the children, what can I do inside this function to have it working ?
>   I mean, for some children it would work as usual, and for some, the
>   parent-view will decide if they will get the touch events or not.

So the question is this: How do I prevent the parent `onTouchEvent()` from overriding some child elements' `onTouchEvent()`, while having it override those of other children?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. The `onTouchEvents()` for nested view groups can be managed by the `boolean` [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).

The default value for the `OnInterceptTouchEvent` is false.

The parent's `onTouchEvent` is received before the child's. If the `OnInterceptTouchEvent` returns false, it sends the motion event down the chain to the child's `OnTouchEvent` handler. If it returns true the parent's will handle the touch event.

However there may be instances when we want some child elements to manage `OnTouchEvent`s and some to be managed by the parent view (or possibly the parent of the parent).

This can be managed in more than one way.

2. One way a child element can be protected from the parent's `OnInterceptTouchEvent` is by implementing the [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)).

> public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean
>   disallowIntercept)

This prevents any of the parent views from managing the `OnTouchEvent` for this element, if the element has event handlers enabled.

3. If the `OnInterceptTouchEvent` is false, the child element's `OnTouchEvent` will be evaluated. If you have a methods within the child elements handling the various touch events, any related event handlers that are disabled will return the OnTouchEvent to the parent.

This answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540006/3956566 gives a good visualisation of how the propagation of touch events passes through:
 `parent -> child|parent -> child|parent -> child views.`

4. Another way is returning varying values from the `OnInterceptTouchEvent` for the parent.

This example taken from [Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)  and demonstrates how to intercept the child's `OnTouchEvent` when the user is scrolling.

4a.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    /*
     * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
     * If we return true, onTouchEvent will be called and we do the actual
     * scrolling there.
     */


    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    // Always handle the case of the touch gesture being complete.
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Release the scroll.
        mIsScrolling = false;
        return false; // Do not intercept touch event, let the child handle it
    }

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mIsScrolling) {
                // We're currently scrolling, so yes, intercept the 
                // touch event!
                return true;
            }

            // If the user has dragged her finger horizontally more than 
            // the touch slop, start the scroll

            // left as an exercise for the reader
            final int xDiff = calculateDistanceX(ev); 

            // Touch slop should be calculated using ViewConfiguration 
            // constants.
            if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) { 
                // Start scrolling!
                mIsScrolling = true;
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

    // In general, we don't want to intercept touch events. They should be 
    // handled by the child view.
    return false;
}
```

Edit: To answer comments.
This is some code from the same link showing how to create the parameters of the rectangle around your element:
4b.

```
// The hit rectangle for the ImageButton
myButton.getHitRect(delegateArea);

// Extend the touch area of the ImageButton beyond its bounds
// on the right and bottom.
delegateArea.right += 100;
delegateArea.bottom += 100;

// Instantiate a TouchDelegate.
// "delegateArea" is the bounds in local coordinates of 
// the containing view to be mapped to the delegate view.
// "myButton" is the child view that should receive motion
// events.
TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, myButton);

// Sets the TouchDelegate on the parent view, such that touches 
// within the touch delegate bounds are routed to the child.
if (View.class.isInstance(myButton.getParent())) {
    ((View) myButton.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand: where is the part that you check that the event don't get passed to certain views? Isn't there supposed to be some x&y coordinates checks inside the view's rectangle ? I actually ask this because I want to have some gestures being set for the parent view (yet being handled in a child), and have the clicking being available only for the child views.

Comment: I have a parent view with a few child-views in it. On of the child-views is special in a way that gestures on the parent are performed on the child-view. I want to leave it this way, except for click events which instead of being performed on the parent-view, will only be performed on the child view. This is why I ask: where&how can I check for the coordinates of the touches, to avoid clicking outside of the child-view.

Comment: Still don't understand. I've managed to successfully do it by creating a "onTouch" function in the childView (includes all its gestures handling), which will be called from the parent view via its onTouchListener, and for the clicking I've made the GestureDetectorCompat check if the event is in the child view (using "getHitRect" and "contains" on the rect). In the activity, I've used "setOnClickListener" on the child view, but also use "setClickable(false)" on it, so that it won't interfere with the gestures.

Comment: There is a point of using setClickable(false) , because the view gets touch events that should be handled in customized gesture detectors, so I don't want to have the normal behavior. About code, I will try to make something, and even put it on Github.

Comment: When I set a click listener, it gets stored and used when I call "performClick" when I've found the gesture of singleTap . However, if I don't call setClickable(false), the touch events cannot be used for the gestures, as they are used on the view instead of its parent. Anyway, I hope to publish a project and show it to you.

Comment: Sorry for this, and thank you for trying to help. Here, have a +1 for the effort . :)

Comment: OK, published an updated repo demonstrating the issue and the solution I've found: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MultiTouchPlaceholderView

Answer (score 2):

Lets revamp the issue.

You happen to have a ViewGroup with a bunch of children. You want to intercept the touch event for everything withing this ViewGroup with a minor exception of some children.

I have been looking for an answer for the same question for quite a while. Did not manage to find anything reasonable and thus came up on my own with the following solution.

The following code snippet provides an overview of the ViewGroup's relevant code that intercepts all touches with the exception of the ones coming from views that happen to have a special tag set (You should set it elsewhere in your code).

```
private static int NO_INTERCEPTION;

private boolean isWithinBounds(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
    int xPoint = Math.round(ev.getRawX());
    int yPoint = Math.round(ev.getRawY());
    int[] l = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();
    return !(xPoint < x || xPoint > x + w || yPoint < y || yPoint > y + h);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    for (int i=0; i<floatingMenuItems.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = floatingMenuItems.getChildAt(i);
        if (child == null || child.getTag(NO_INTERCEPTION) == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if(isWithinBounds(child, ev)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```