# Prevent parent from getting touch events only for certain views?

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

I have a `ScrollView` and linear layout inside it. Inside the linear layout i have multiple views. One of the multiple views (DrawView lets say)is used to draw stuff so i have to override `onTouchEvent` of that method and draw things. Currently when i drag or move  on the `DrawView`, the `ScrollView` also handles the touch leading the entire view moving. What i want is that when i touch the `DrawView` , the scroll view should not move . I went through some of these answers here

[How to vary between child and parent view group touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966412/how-to-vary-between-child-and-parent-view-group-touch-events)

but i did not find anything that i can add in `DrawView` which will prevent the `ScrollView` from moving up and down. Note that `DrawView` does not extend `ViewGroup` so i don't have access to [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `ScrollView` from your `DrawView`'s `onTouchEvent`:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getParent();
```

then you can call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` on `scrollView` to prevent it from scrolling when you touch the `DrawView`.

```
scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Comment: Thanks , i did something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent scroll of ScrollView whenever your DrawView gets touch event. To do That you need to create a custom ScrollView calls like below <sup>[[Original Code Snippet]](https://learnpainless.com/android/scrollview/create-custom-scrollview-to-enable-or-disable-scrolling)</sup>

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private boolean enableScrolling = true;
    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (scrollingEnabled()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (scrollingEnabled()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean scrollingEnabled(){
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }
}
```

And you can call `scrollView.setScrolling(true/false)` as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks this is a valid solution but a simpler solution would be the one suggested by @Hong Duan.

Answer (score 1):

So i ended up doing this in my `DrawView` in the `onTouchEvent` method

`getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` , it worked!