# Disable DrawerLayout's scrim touch gesture

Tags: android, touch, gesture, drawerlayout

[image]

I need to disable touch gesture on the scrim (the red highlighted part). I want to dismiss the drawer only with the swipe.

The issue is that when the drawer layout is open and I need to select an element from the ListView below the red highlighted part, what's happend is that the drawer get closed and only at this point I can select an element from the ListView.

I need to select the element from the ListView directly, also when the Drawer is opened

Comment: The red panel is just to highlight the portion of UI where I need to manage the Drawer's on click in a custom way. I draw it with Photoshop

Comment: I'll try your code tomorrow, thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create custom drawer for that like this

```
public class CustomDrawer extends DrawerLayout {



    public CustomDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public CustomDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)){
            if(event.getX() > getChildAt(1).getWidth()){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Note : `getChildAt(1)` should be that child to whom you have given gravity as "start" and whose width determines the width of opening drawer.

I hope this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I asked an answered a question here:
[How to vary between child and parent view group touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966412/how-to-vary-between-child-and-parent-view-group-touch-events)

The `parent` (`drawer`) `ontouchevent` is being fired, rather than the `child`, `listview`.

I have also answered a similar problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180281/3956566

You need to manage your touch events so it is handled by the child. You need to use an `onInterceptTouchEvent` and return false.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // returning false means the child will handle the touch event.
    return false;
}
```

You then manage you `touchevent` for the list view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // This method will only be called if the touch event was intercepted in 
    // onInterceptTouchEvent
    // TODO Select your listview item.

}
```

You can also determine what type of touch event is taking place eg, scrolling and determine whether the child or parent will manage the event.

[Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

I've added this quote from here [Understanding Android Input Touch Events System Framework (dispatchTouchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent, OnTouchListener.onTouch)](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/):

> The root view starts dispatching the event down to its children. Let’s
>   presume that we have this hierarchy:
>
> A – ViewGroup1 (parent of B).
>     B – ViewGroup2 (parent of C).
>     C – View (child of B)
>   – receives a touch/tap/click. Now the root view will call
>   A.dispatchTouchEvent(). Now the job of a ViewGroup.dispatchEvent()
>   (not View.dispatchEvent()) is to find out all the child views and view
>   groups whose bounds contain the touch point coordinates (using a hit
>   testing algorithm). When it figures out a list of relevant children,
>   it starts dispatching the events to them by calling their
>   dispatchTouchEvent().
>
> Here’s an important piece though. Before the dispatchTouchEvent() is
>   called on the children, the A.dispatchTouchEvent() will first call
>   A.onInterceptTouchEvent() to see if the view group is interested in
>   intercepting the event and handling the subsequent gesture by itself
>   (scrolling is a good use case where a fling on B should lead to
>   scrolling on A). The method onInterceptTouchEvent() is only available
>   on view groups (as they’re the one who can be parents/containers with
>   the requirement to intercept touch events) that can sort of keep an
>   eye on the event and hijack it by returning true. If it returns false
>   then dispatching continues as usual, i.e., B.dispatchTouchEvent()
>   (child) will be called. But on returning true, this is what’ll happen:
>
> ACTION_CANCEL will be dispatched to all the children.
>   All the
>   subsequent gesture events (till ACTION_UP/ACTION_CANCEL) will be
>   consumed by the event listeners (OnTouchListener.onTouch()) if
>   defined, else the event handler A.onTouchEvent() at A’s level.
>   A.onInterceptTouchEvent() itself will be never called again.

[With this diagram:](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/)

[image: diagram of touch event propagation]

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score -2):

just add `android:clickable="true"` to drawer menu.