# Content in FrameLayout scrollable in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

I want to scroll RecyclerView in FrameLayout when Drawer is opened (swiped to "open" position). I can't do it now, because FrameLayout is covered by Drawer. When I'm clicking on it - Drawer disappears and RecyclerView in FrameLayout is scrollable. How can I do it? Any properties in .xml or programmatically?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Resolved! I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31769539/3186095) solution! Wrong words used to search :) Thx for attention!

Comment: It works good, but now my recyclerView scrolling is not smoothly... Scroll stopps after small segment scrolled. Any idea?